# Two tomcat 7 instance running on same machine not accepting requests on AJP connector

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I have setup a tomcat cluster with session replication running on same machine. I have modified the connector and shutdown ports as

node1
--http      8080
--ajp       8009
--shutdown  8005
node2
--http      9080
--ajp       9009
--shutdown  9005

When i configure a load balancer in front of these nodes (httpd 2.2.15 on a centOs server) on two ajp ports

The problem is balancer is not able to connect to the ajp connector and it goer to error state.

When i configure the same with http protocol for the node2 it works. I didnt try these with the two nodes on two different machines.

Tomcat does not give any problem, logs are absolutely ok. all these ports become occupied when  two nodes are started up.

Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual error...

The problem was due to firewall was blocking the access..

Solution is to disable the firewall for the private IP ethernet card if the machine(s) has two cards.
Or disable entire firewall.
Or selectively allow configured ports in iptable..